# How to make bootstrap progressbar span full width between <td>?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How can we get the bootstrap progress bar to span the full width between the two badges?

[image]

I tried this, but it didn't solve the problem:

```
.progress {
margin-bottom: 0px;
width: 70%;
}
```

The index:

```
  <tr>
    <td>
      <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">
      Level <span class="badge"><%= challenged.current_level %></span>
      </button>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="progress">
      <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="10" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="10" style="width: 60%;">
      <%= challenged.current_level %>
      </div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">
      Strike <span class="badge"><%= [params[:missed]].flatten.length %></span>
      </button>
    </td>
  </tr>
```

### EDIT

**Full index**

```
 <table>
    <% @habits.each do |challenged| %>
    <tbody>
          <tr>
              <td>
                  Level <span class="badge"><%= challenged.current_level %></span>
              </td>
              <td>
                  <div class="progress">
                      <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="10" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="10" style="width: 60%;">
                          <%= challenged.current_level %>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </td>
              <td>
                  Strike <span class="badge"><%= [params[:missed]].flatten.length %></span>
              </td>
          </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><span class="label label-primary">AFTER I</span> <%= challenged.trigger %>,
          <span class="label label-primary">I WILL</span>
            <%= raw challenged.tag_list.map { |t| link_to t.titleize, tag_path(t), class: 'label label-info' }.join(' ') %>
          <span class="label label-primary">UNTIL</span> <%= challenged.target %>
          <span class="label label-primary">SO I CAN</span> <%= challenged.reward %>
            <span class="label label-primary"><%= challenged.committed.map { |d| d.titleize[0,3] }.join ', ' %></span></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
  <% end %>
  </table>
```

I tried such things as removing td's adding td's, changing div's so I think I narrowed it down to having to override something in the progress bar default code.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `width: 100%;` to the middle cell:

**HTML:**

```
<table class="table">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Level <span class="badge">1</span></td>
            <td class="stretch vam">
                <div class="progress m0">
                    <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="10" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="10" style="width: 60%;">text</div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>Strike <span class="badge">1</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">
                <span class="label label-primary">Label</span> more text
                <span class="label label-primary">Label</span> more text
                <span class="label label-primary">Label</span> more text
                <span class="label label-primary">Label</span> more text
                <span class="label label-primary">Label</span> more text
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**CSS:**

```
td.stretch {
    width: 100%;
}
```

[JSFiddle demo:](http://jsfiddle.net/s5ebx3j4/2/)

Comment: Thanks for trying Cookie. It got the bar to be longer as hoped, but not long enough. There is also text below it (not shown in question) that is now smushed to the left before where the progress bar starts above it.

Comment: Yyou mean there is text after `.progress` or after `.progress-bar` div? Could you provide whole html code? :)

Comment: I updated my answet, but please look at the jsfiddle demo. What you probably need to add is colspan="3" attribute to the cell of the second row. Hope this will help you :)